# NPM can't be install because of GYP ERR with Node v16

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

Hello guys I am having the following problem, I am having project that I have to run but when I try to install npm it fails whit this log [see the log from webstorm here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHOMQ.png) The version of node is 16.14.1, npm is 6.19.3, node-gyp is 8.4.1

Have you encounter that issue before?

If I downgrade to node v14 it passes but the pipeline files because of docker image of node that is 16 and also different errors on local start to appear because of prettier.

I have researched all of the issues regarding gyp but havent found a solution to my problem, deleted node and all of it's cache but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

There seems versions for `node` and `node-gyp` are incompatible. Can you try using the latest `node-gyp` version i.e `9.3.1`? Hopefully this will resolve your issue.